# AD security groups renamed. PeoplePicker in Sharepoint 2010 still shows old values

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, groups

Sharepoint 2010.
Our IT guys have recently renamed many Active Directory security groups, however PeoplePicker appears to now display both the old name and new name in results. I assume the new name is coming directly from AD, but the old name is coming from the sharepoint content database UserInfo table. Additionally, if we assign permissions to one of the 2 returned results, when next searching for the same group, sharepoint appears to have merged the information for the 2 groups together and so only one result is returned. However, it is keeping the old (incorrect) "title" rather than the new one.

I'm wondering if anyone has any solutions for this issue?
I know I can locate the "group" in Site Settings > People and Groups, and click "Delete user from Site Collection", but then I will lose any permissions set for this group within my sharepoint site. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

User information is stored in a hidden list (User Information List) in each site Collection. I guess the old information comes from there.

Have you run stsadm -o migrategroup command for the Groups that were renamed?

Check-out this blog - it mentions your display name issue: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031211007/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/joerg_sinemus/archive/2010/09/28/moss-running-stsadm-o-migrategroup-command-keeps-the-old-group-name-and-does-not-replace-with-the-new-name.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help out ,

http://blog.aptillon.com/tag/user-information-list/

I tried it out and this resolved my issues as well.

Thanks,
John.

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for SP2010, but by experience in 2007 it was like that:

The SharePoint groups won't be updated, but the SP groups will be able to work without.

See this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/d9d4060a-11b4-4d7a-93f7-8b9803f10c5d

Did you try a User Profile synchronization?

Comment: Thanks for the response Seb. Yes, I've seen that article actually. It mentions either "editing" the incorrect names - but doesn't explain how to do that, or simply deleting and re-creating them which I was trying to avoid as I will lose any permissions that have been set. Perhaps deleting them is my only option. Does anyone know how to determine where an Active Directory security group has been assigned permissions within a Sharepoint site?

Answer (score 0):

To determine that you go to Site Actions -> site settings, better site permissions. You find Site Actions in left corner, or within a library also under library permissions, right corner of contextual tabs.
There you have an overviwe about all permissions set. You need sufficient right to change, but you should be able to list and see.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to rename Sharepoint groups by PowerShell. See the link below to know how to update SharePoint groups:
[Update Sharepoint group displayname](http://ittalk.info/sharepoint/renaming-an-active-directory-ad-group-in-sharepoint-20102013)